# how to get float values from form in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have search everywhere on SOF but none of solution worked for me, I need help with calculating float values from a form to javascript on keypress.

I have two fields in form & I want to calculate the values.

```
<input name="Package[sms]" id="Package_sms" type="text">
<input name="Package[sms_rate]" id="Package_sms_rate" type="text">
```

Here is my javascript code.

```
$('#Package_sms, #Package_sms_rate').keypress(function () {
     var sms = parseFloat($("#Package_sms").val());
     var rate = parseFloat($("#Package_sms_rate").val());
     console.log(rate);
     // other code
     console.log(sms*rate);
});
```

I'm trying to get the value of `Package_sms_rate`, When I input the value `0.1`, the console shows `0.1` perfectly but when I input any of these values `0.11` or `0.12` to `0.19`, it still shows `0.1`. It is making wrong calculations because of that. How do i fix it?

```
sms = 50000
rate = 0.1
total = 5000

sms = 50000
rate = 0.1 // when i enter 0.12
total = 5000 // still showing 5000, it should be 6000 for rate 0.12
```

Comment: Have you tried the "keyup"-Event?

Comment: No i haven't tried

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan I think `$('#Package_sms, #Package_sms_rate').on('input', function(){` should work just fine for this too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `keypress` event to a `keyup` event, so that it triggers after the value has been applied to the input:

*Note: I replaced your `parseFloat()` by the `+` operator, it's shorter and much more versatile.*

```js
$('#Package_sms, #Package_sms_rate').keyup(function () {
     var sms = +$("#Package_sms").val();
     var rate = +$("#Package_sms_rate").val();
     console.log(rate);
     console.log(sms*rate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Package[sms]" id="Package_sms" type="text">
<input name="Package[sms_rate]" id="Package_sms_rate" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks `keyup` worked :)